# Rigidbody Projectile Being Suspended In Mid-Air

Tags: unity, projectile-physics, rigidbody

I am experiencing problems with Unity's Rigibody feature. Whenever I try firing a projectile, it gets suspended in mid-air. The projectiles are stored in an object pool. Below is the code and images of the problem:

Images:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
void FixedUpdate (){
//Logic for firing bullets
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && firingBullets < 50) 
{
    //Bullets are being stored as a pool. If isKinematic of all the bullets is set to false before it is fired from the gun, all the bullets in the pool will scatter
    bulletProjectile [firingBullets].isKinematic = false;


    bulletProjectile [firingBullets].AddForce (bulletProjectile [firingBullets].transform.up * 10000f);


    //Sets the bullet Transform independant of parent object (which is the weapon) upon firing. If it's not set to null, then the bullet will follow the weapon along x-axis (side-to-side).
    transform.Find (bulletProjectile [firingBullets].name).parent = null;


    //Reference to next bullet
    firingBullets++;
}
}
```

The reason why I change the isKinematic value is because if it is set to false during runtime, then all the bullets inside the weapon will scatter.

The size of the bullets has no effect on this problem. I've enlargened the bullets so that it would be easier to view.

Comment: Why are you storing bullets in an array or list?? Why do you don't want to instantiate bullet during the gameplay?

Comment: Firing projectiles at a high rate will put a lot of strain on the overall performance. It's best to use an object pool for this instance, instead of Instantiating/Destroying each and every bullet. Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dave_crooks_dev_blog/archive/2014/07/21/object-pooling-for-unity3d.aspx)
and this [one](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalScriptingOptimizations.html)

Comment: I'm not too sure if storing the bullet pool in a list is the best idea. I'm just concentrating on getting this problem solved for now and then I will research on optimizing

Comment: Rather than this, I'd suggest to create a small and tiny Bullet class in which bullets will always going straight and would able to send message on collision.

Comment: Yes. It looks like I will have to create a workaround to this problem